# pathlib resolve() method not resolving non-existant files

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pathlib

The `resolve()` method in Python 3.6.1's `pathlib` does not seem to be working properly. (Using Anaconda 4.4.0 release)

Given the following program:

```py
from pathlib import Path
parent_dir = ("/tmp/test2")
file_path=Path("a.txt")
path = parent_dir / file_path
print("PARENT_DIR: ", parent_dir)
print("FILE_PATH: ", file_path)
print("PATH: ", path)
print("PATH.RESOLVE(): ",path.resolve(strict=False))
```

I would expect to see `/tmp/test2/a.txt` printed as `PATH.RESOLVE()` even though `/tmp/test2` does not exist.

Instead I see this:

```
% > python bug.py
PARENT_DIR:  /tmp/test2
FILE_PATH:  a.txt
PATH:  /tmp/test2/a.txt
PATH.RESOLVE():  /tmp/test2
```

The [pathlib documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pathlib.html) says this:

> If the path doesn’t exist and strict is True, FileNotFoundError is raised. If strict is False, the path is resolved as far as possible and any remainder is appended without checking whether it exists. If an infinite loop is encountered along the resolution path, RuntimeError is raised.

As a final test of the bug, if I create `/tmp/test2` I get the expected behavior:

```sh
> mkdir /tmp/test2
> python bug.py
PARENT_DIR:  /tmp/test2
FILE_PATH:  a.txt
PATH:  /tmp/test2/a.txt
PATH.RESOLVE():  /tmp/test2/a.txt
>
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Additional Note: This program runs properly on Mojave on Python 3.6.3.  The above result was with Red Hat 6.10

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a bug in pathlib2-2.2.1.  It is fixed in pathlib2-2.3.0.